# TFS Custom DateTime Field Format not accepted

Tags: tfs

Reading this article http://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/custom-date-format-for-the-work-item-datetimecontrol-tfs2010/ I was trying to create a new field with the Type **DateTimeControl** and the Field Name **Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate**

Since I do not want to see the time for this field, I have added two custom attributes to the definition:

```
Format=Custom
CustomFormat=dd.MM.yyyy
```

When I hit preview in the Power Tools 2013 in VS 2013 I can select the date and it is formated according to the setting. I can write other stuff in the Custom Format and in the preview it works.

When I upload it to the server, however the format is always **dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt**, it does never change.
I have a custom locale for my user,  which I suspected was an issue here, but my locale setting for time is **h:mm** without the AM/PM but the field in the work item still always shows me **12:00 AM**

Is this a locale issue, or why does the preview differ from the "reality"? The generated xml for the configurations above with the Work Item Editor looks correctly (proper attributes are inserted into the xml:

```
<Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate" Type="DateTimeControl" Label="Target Date" Format="Custom" CustomFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The format tag does work, but (I love it where there is always a but), it works only in Visual Studio view and not Web View. I have also encountered this issue and still didn't find a good solution for the web client.

Aaron